# Apple App Store review rejection for in-app consumable purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

I have an app that uses in-app purchases and works in TestFlight as I would expect with the purchases, but keeps being rejected. This last rejection they say I need to submit a build with them in-app purchases enabled. But in my app it is enabled and it works in TestFlight. What am I missing?  Is there some hidden thing that I need to do?  The capability is enabled in the app manifest. I’m kind of lost, and they aren’t giving me any specific feedback about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK! Facepalm moment for me!  I forgot to:

1. Add the in-app purchase screenshots
2. Add the in-app purchase to the review request

I forgot totally that they are separately added, I would have come around to the answer days/hours/minutes faster if the responses from them were more descriptive, and I was more attentive...LOL